# Using arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have the  arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management() script working however I want to have the extent of which the tool tiles set to a layer and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the syntax. Below is a link to the ESRI documentation:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm

Here is a small bit of code with example code I wrote. I'm hoping someone can chime in and guide me in the correct direction on how to use the correct syntax on getting the tool to use the extent of a layer.

```
arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management(mxd_file_name, "ONLINE", lyr.datasetName + ".tpk", "PNG8", "10", EXTENT = <Conductor>)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your linked documentation you just need to specify the layer name.  You don't need to put it between `<` and `>` characters.  These are just shown in the docs to show that you don't type the actual word "Layer" as you would for `DISPLAY`, `MAXOF`, `MINOF` extent options.

> Specify the extent by manually entering the coordinates in the extent
>   parameter using the format X-Min Y-Min X-Max Y-Max. **To use the extent
>   of a specific layer, specify the layer name**.

In the last parameter of your tool example you have `EXTENT = <Conductor>` - basically you want to specify the name of your layer here, or a variable that references your layer somehow.

If the name of your layer is "Conductor" you could put

```
myLayer = 'Conductor'

arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management(mxd_file_name, "ONLINE", lyr.datasetName + ".tpk", "PNG8", "10", extent=myLayer)
```

Or you could reference the layer directly in the tool

```
arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management(mxd_file_name, "ONLINE", lyr.datasetName + ".tpk", "PNG8", "10", extent='Conductor')
```